# Jmeter Test Does not Stop

Tags: module, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am using Jmeter 3.2.1 with JDK8

I have a test plan with three subsequences:
   1: Login
   2: Discover
   3: List
   4: Create new element

I initially had these as a single monolith SimpleController. And it worked fine.

I modularized it as 4 modules, with the main thread group ("Main Test")
invoking each module in sequence as follows:

[image: My Test Plan with modules]

After I created module controller, the test does not stop, although
it does not doing anything else (according to my debug postprocessor).

What am I missing?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a Test Action with "Stop" of All Threads.

However, I do not understand why this is required. If I exit my last module